# Insert Custom Cell into TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that populates custom cells based on incoming data:

```
var posts: [PostViewModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to insert a different custom cell that has nothing to do with the array i.e. a reminder for the user to subscribe or login. The Index Path set should look like this for example:

1. Post Cell
2. Post Cell
3. Post Cell
4. Login Cell
5. Post Cell
6. etc...

How would I go about this approach as the cell has nothing to do with the model.

Thanks.

Comment: The cell **does** have something to do with the model. Reloading the table view in `didSet` is bad practice anyway because you throw away the ability to insert/delete/move cells animated.

Comment: There are different ways to do this. One way by adding an extra variable into the PostViewModel like login= true and inserting newly created PostViewModel object into the array before reloading tableview.So that you can use custom tableViewCell for login.

Comment: you should use enum.

Comment: How about making a custom view that lies on top of one of the cells in your tableview? Then you don't have to mess with your data source.

Comment: @good4pc I already have a variable for the style of the cell.  So I guess I could add it to that.  I assume that I would need to create a custom initializer if the cell is style: login so that I don't have to initialise all the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my practice it is better to create custom type of cell. And add this type as a property to your PostViewModel. After that you can recognize what type of cell you should to dequeue. For example:

```
// Type of custom cell
enum PostsType {
    case postCell
    case loginCell
}

struct PostViewModel {
    let type: PostsType
    // another View model data
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var posts: [PostViewModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellType = posts[indexPath.row].type

        switch cellType {
        case .loginCell:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoginCell", for: indexPath)
        case .postCell:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach, however, I think I will need to implement custom initialisers within the model based on what type of 'cell' it is.

Comment: @DavidLintin thank you. You can refactor your ViewModel regarding this approach. And one way is that you said, it's create custom init for your model.